# updating .net 4 site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Ive just made live a site for a client,
I need to now update it with both design and logic changes.
WHats the best way to do this? Never done it before.

I know I cant just overwrite the amended aspx and aspx.cs files, tried that and although the design changes take effect the coding doesnt.

Any info appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rebuild the binary in Visual Studio, and upload the DLL to the bin folder. The cs files don't even need to live on the server.

Comment: the aspx pages need to be put on though, yeah?